# I want to force https request to http in express js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, http, redirect

I do not have ssl so I want my website should only be serve on http. but now when we hit https it says the site can not be accessed.
is there any way we can redirect https request to http ??

```
const express = require('express') 
const Router = express.Router()
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
app.use(Router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname ,  '../reactjs-admin-panel/build' )))
app.get('*', (req, res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../reactjs-admin-panel/build'));
}) 
app.listen(80);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to redirect from https to http is to have both an https server and an http server.  You would have an https server that would accept the https request and then redirect to http (which may also generate a browser warning).  So, you would need a full-on https server with certificate, etc... to do that.  And, once you had a full-on https server, you may as well just let the user use it rather than redirect to the less secure http.

So, if you don't have https server up, then you can't respond to https requests in any way, not even just to redirect to http.  So, basically, there isn't a way to do what you're asking without already having an https server configured and working.